# jQuery function that modifies a DIV

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery

How can I shorten and optimize this code which displays then hides a `DIV`?

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.updateNotification').show().addClass('heightener');
    callback();
},2000)

function callback() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $( '.updateNotification' ).fadeOut();
  }, 10000 );
};
```

My first thought was to combine the functions. However, I would like them to remain separate because at a later date I will additionally incorporate a button which will trigger `callback()` in addition to the timer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would shorten this code. However I think that `callback` is a *terrible* name for a function that fades a CSS class. Remember that a function signature should represent what a function does and with that said I would rename it to something like `fadeUpdateNotification()`.

And in the fashion of fading you could replace `.show()` with `.fadeIn()` to have the div fade in and out - I dunno how your styling/website looks like but that might look nice...

Answer (score 3):

There's not much here to optimize mostly because there's very little here. A few things you could do:

Store your selection to a variable outside both functions (bad idea if you may have multiple notificationDivs).

```
var notificationDiv = $( '.updateNotification' )
```

You could save 1 character by adding the callback to the `show` animation (not really an improvement):

```
notificationDiv.show(0,callback)
```

I'm more confused about why you're doing the `setTimeout`s the way you are. Why do you need a 2 second delay to show the div? Also if you plan to call `callback` later, I think it'd confuse most people if the div takes 10 seconds to start to disappear.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PSLeQ/) I used while tinkering.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to combine them you can just do it like this

```
$('.updateNotification').delay(2000).show(0).addClass('heightener').delay(10000).fadeOut();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4XYg8/

or to keep the callback function something like this

```
var notifications= $('.updateNotification'); //store the selection like Daniel Cook said
setTimeout(function () {
    //if you use the no-arguments form of .show()
    //you can just add display:block on the class .heightener
    notifications.addClass('heightener');
    callback();
},2000);

function callback() {
    notifications.delay(10000).fadeOut();//if you only want to fadeOut you can use delay
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4XYg8/1/

Comment: I knew someone would know the "correct" way to combine it. +1